# Automatically creates a user after signing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a simple app using Devise.
How can I automatically create and assign a user to a new client when they signup?

I have a clients table and affiliate table, they both need a user, so I created a user table and clients and affiliates belong to User.

The idea is that after a user signs up it creates both client and user with the email given and an automatically generated password that the client will receive on their email. When they log in they will be prompted to change the password.

I have a landing page for clients to sign up, they put their info and click sign_up. What I wanted is to auto-generate a user for that client so they can log in next time they visit.

This is what I tried so far:

clients_controller.rb

```
   def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params)
    @user = User.new(user_params[password: random_password, password_confirmation: random_password])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.save && @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @client }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


   private

    def set_client
      @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    end

    def client_params
      params.require(:client).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :cellphone, :email, :affiliate_id, :user_id)
    end

  def user_params
    params.require(:client).permit(:email)
  end

  def random_password
    [*('a'..'z'),*('0'..'9')].shuffle[0,8].join
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change 
`@user = User.new(user_params[password: random_password, password_confirmation: random_password])`

to

```
user_parameter = user_params.merge(password: random_password, password_confirmation: random_password)

@user = User.create!(user_parameter)
```

Comment: Thanks, man. I think the random password was being generated every time it was called, so it didn't match. So I created a variable to store it and then called the variable instead: 
  def user_parameter
    random_number = random_password
    user_params.merge(password: random_number, password_confirmation: random_number)
  end

Comment: Any Idea of how I can collect the user id and save it on the user_id under the client?

Comment: I used @client.update_columns(user_id: @user.id) and called it if saved.